# Javascript - my setTimeOut in a while loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I wanted to do something like this:

```
<p id="sec">5</p>
<script>
var i = 5;
while (i > 0){
    setTimeout(i--,1000);
    document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = i;
}
if (i === 0){
    window.location = "index.php";
}
</script>
```

And without a split second, it redirected me to index.php? Why does this happened? How to make it work?

Comment: `setTimeout` takes a function to execute sometimes later, and returns immediately.

Comment: replace your setTimeout with: `setTimeout(alert("hi!"),1000);` and you will understand what's happening really. PS: remove the redirect, just for testing purposes.

Comment: @TheBronx The "sec" stayed 5?! Sorry but I don't understand.

Comment: you have to understand that setTimeout does not stop execution of the script. It's not like a "sleep" function. A more simple example, two lines: `setTimeout(function(){alert("timeout finished!")},5000);alert("hey, no waiting");` See what happens, which alert comes first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var i = 5;
setTimeout(updateTime,1000);

function updateTime()
{
    document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = i--;

    if (i === 0)
        window.location = "index.php";
    else
        setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I tried but the sec stayed 5 also.

Comment: works just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/aXKB3/

Comment: +1, This is the best answer here because it won't lock up the CPU. Also because your name is _Paul_. This could also be achieved using `window.setInterval`.

Comment: @DanielCheung check the javascript console for errors

Comment: @PaulS. some people shun `setInterval`

Comment: I like the way that with `setTimeout` then you only need set a further timeout if a know that another event is needed. With `setInterval` I feel responsible for explicitly setting the timer to null when I'm done with it. Also, `setTimeout` is great for when your action takes longer than your interval...

Comment: @JanDvorak as long as you remember to `clearInterval` and **the interval is longer than the execution time** it's basically the same as using `setTimeout` like this. If you have code that takes so long you should start using `Date` rather than some integer.

Comment: @paul I found that if you type `updateTime();` instead of `setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);`, there will be no pause before the first count.